# Is it possible to wrap a type for use only within an expression in C#?

Tags: c#

I am trying to implement a repository pattern and to do so I want to abstract the data provider, but still retain the ability to join tables.

I have decided to achieve this with an expression tree and would like my syntax to look like this:

```
var repo = new Repository<Role>();
repo.JoinData(
        r => r
            .Join(r => r.RolePermissions)
            .Join(rp => rp.Permission),
        r => r
            .Join(r => r.RoleCategories)
            .Join(rc => rc.Category),
        r => r
            .Join(r => r.RoleCategories)
            .Join(rc => rc.CategoryType)
    )
```

My problem is that the lamda's parameters 'r', which is of type 'Role' doesnt have a Join method on it. I would like to extend the type, but only have that extension usable from with the context of this method. The Join method does not actually have to perform anything as I will be taking apart the expression and using it for other means.

Is this possible?

Comment: I'm not sure about your experience level or what problem you're trying to solve, but I would caution you about adding a repository layer on top of entity framework. Before diving I would suggest doing a lot of research on it: https://www.thereformedprogrammer.net/is-the-repository-pattern-useful-with-entity-framework-core/.

Comment: Right, EF's `DbSet<T>` class *is* a repository, and the `DbContext` is the unit-of-work.

Comment: `I would like to extend the type, but only have that extension usable from with the context of this method.`  I don't think this is possible.

Comment: Not to argue but the fact DbContext implements x or y doesn't address that using EF and its Entity classes directly in upper layers is also a bad design decision unless of course being vendor locked is a desirable outcome.

Comment: @ChiefTwoPencils vendor locking, and separation of concerns for unit testing is why I have gone this route, but If I cant figure this one out I may have to give up on it.

Ideally if I could abstract data manipulation away from controllers that would be best I think since there will be complete standardisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems it is not possible, the closest I got was Oliver's answer

Answer (score -1):

In a static class, declare these extension methods:

```
public static class JoinExtensions
{
    public static U Join<T, U>(this T input, Func<T, U> project)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Can only be used in expression lambdas");
    }

    public static U Join<T, U>(this ICollection<T> input, Func<T, U> project)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException("Can only be used in expression lambdas");
    }
}
```

The `throw` statements in the body of the extension methods ensure that you cannot call them in another context than in an `Expression<T>`. Unfortunately, you cannot enforce it at compile-time.

The `JoinData` method looks like this

```
public static void JoinData(params Expression<Func<Role, object>>[] joins)
{
    foreach (var join in joins) {
        Console.WriteLine(join); // You would evaluate the Expressions here.
    }
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

With this call

```
JoinData(
    r => r
        .Join(r => r.RolePermissions)
        .Join(rp => rp.Permission),
    r => r
        .Join(r => r.RoleCategories)
        .Join(rc => rc.Category),
    r => r
        .Join(r => r.RoleCategories)
        .Join(rc => rc.CategoryType)
);
```

you get the following output in the console:

> r => r.Join(r => r.RolePermissions).Join(rp => rp.Permission)
>   r => r.Join(r => r.RoleCategories).Join(rc => rc.Category)
>   r => r.Join(r => r.RoleCategories).Join(rc => rc.CategoryType)

This proves, that the expressions reflect the lambdas as expected.

---

I have tested with these entity classes:

```
public class Role
{
    public ICollection<RolePermission> RolePermissions { get; }
    public ICollection<RoleCategory> RoleCategories { get; }
}

public class RolePermission
{
    public Permission Permission { get; }
}

public class RoleCategory
{
    public Category Category { get; }
    public CategoryType CategoryType { get; }
}

public class Category { }
public class CategoryType { }
public class Permission { }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. He doesn't want an extension method that can be used in lambda expressions. He wants an extension that can ONLY be used in lambda expressions, which is not possible.

Comment: @DetectivePikachu: You can solve this very simply by having a `throw` statement into the extension methods, since in an `Expression<>` the methods are never called.

Comment: This answer is very helpful, after all I dont actually need to run the delegate, just evaluate the expression.

I think with your edit this is way better than what I have. Thanks!